# время выполнения всех моих функций 0.00000c, что не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

```
def timeit(f):
    import time

    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time.time()
        # time.sleep(1)
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Время выполнения функции: %f" % (time.time()-t))
        return res

    return tmp

@timeit
def foo(a,b):
    print(a*b)
    print(a + b)
    print(a / b)
    print(a - b)
    print(a*b*a*b*b*b)

foo(a=1000, b=4567890)
```

foo-только для примера, 0.00000c дает результат абсолютно на всех функциях. Делала проверку с паузой time.sleep(1), тогда все работает. Подскажите плиз, что не так

Comment: а оно действительно сильно дольше работает?

Comment: не сильно... но с паузой в 1 сек=> 1.000268, разница ж есть

Comment: @galina операции скорее всего быстро выполняются, а 0.000268 это вместе с инициализацией time.sleep(). Проверил у себя: при добавлении time.sleep(1) время сильно вырастает (относительно без слипа). Без слипа результат ~0.000061, со слипом ~1.002961

Comment: Вот поэтому в Jupyter магическая команда %timeit крутит на таких функциях миллионы циклов, чтобы хоть какую-то адекватную статистику наработать. И вообще у вас слишком быстрый компьютер, в Google Colab всё-таки не ноль выходит: Время выполнения функции: 0.002591

Comment: @CrazyElf работаю на очень посредственном ноуте,  и частенько pycharm виснет. Вот я и удивилась таким показателям)

Comment: @galia Ну, может pycharm просто ssd диск хочет, а его нет. Или памяти мало. А процессор может и неплохой при этом. Тогда может быть так. :)

Comment: @CrazyElf оу, поняла..спасибо)